# how to handle reset layout?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm now getting this error:

> __layout.reset has been removed in favour of named layouts: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/layouts#named-layouts

I have a sub-directory for which I do not want to inherit the base layout.

```
$ find . -name '*layout*'               
./setup-profile/__layout.reset.svelte
./auth/__layout.reset.svelte
./__layout.svelte
```

package.json has

```
    "@sveltejs/kit": "next",
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't work anymore as [the routing system evolved](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing#advanced-layouts).

My understanding is that:

- all layout inherit from the root layout `+page.svelte`
- but you can create groups which are not taken into account in the final path of your route.

For example, we can imagine that a website has a layout containing a header, a main and a footer block.

But we may also have some king of popups that are not comprised of these block elements, but instead, they are simple blocks with a high `z-index` or something like this.

Because all layouts inherits the root layout, we can just create a blank layout at the root (containing a single `<slot />`), and then, we create an `(app)` group  and a `(popup)` group (parenthesis are crucial here). And inside of each group, you define the layout that will be inherited by all the layouts located in the respective sub folders.

It would gives us something like below:

```bash
src/routes
├── (app)
│   ├── +layout.svelte ----> contains Header, Main, Footer etc.
│   ├── page1
│   │   └── +page.svelte
│   ├── page2
│   │   └── +page.svelte
│   ├── page3
│   │   └── +page.svelte
├── (popup)
|   ├── +layout.svelte ----> contains only popup HTML & styles
│   ├── popup
│       └── popup1
│       │   └── +page.svelte
│       └── popup2
│           └── +page.svelte
├── (test)
│   ├── +layout.svelte
│   └── test
│       ├── +layout.svelte
│       └── page.svelte
├── +error.svelte
├── +layout.svelte  ----> contains nothing or only global things
├── +page.svelte
└── api
    ├── user
    │   └── [uid]
    │         └── get.json
    └── ...
...
```

Comment: This was useful and helped a lot.

Answer (score 8):

The doc page you linked is pretty self-explanatory.

**Edit:**

Overall the simpler way is to create a named reset layout at the root of your source tree containing a simple `<slot />`, and reference that layout whenever you want to start from a reset layout:

```
src/routes/
├ auth/
│ ├ __layout@reset.svelte (will inherit from the reset layout)
│ ├ pageA.svelte
│ └ pageB.svelte
├ setup-profile/
│ ├ __layout@reset.svelte (will inherit from the reset layout)
│ ├ pageA.svelte
│ └ pageB.svelte
├ no-reset/
│ ├ __layout.svelte (will inherit from the base layout)
│ ├ pageA.svelte
│ └ pageB.svelte
├ __layout.svelte
└ __layout-reset.svelte
```

Comment: `> Files and directories prefixed with __ are reserved (saw src/routes/__layout-reset.svelte)`

Comment: had to remove `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`

Comment: This explanation helps exactly the behaviour I am seeing, so thanks. The confusion is that the docs say: "Ordinarily, this would inherit the root layout, the (app) layout, the item layout and the [id] layout. We can reset to one of those layouts by appending @ followed by the segment name" which to me reads the opposite behaviour https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing#advanced-layouts-breaking-out-of-layouts

Comment: @aroundtheworld glad I could help a bit, but keep in mind my answer above is obsolete if you are using more recent versions of SvelteKit where routing conventions have been updated! However if you have a specific question or need regarding the use of layouts I'd be able to assist if I can.

Comment: thanks @ThomasHennes, i am using svelte 3.5.4 - using groups, noticing that routes/(app)>layout.svelte is taken by every child +page. As the docs read, it sounded like using the +page@[id].svelte meant the root or (app) layout was not taken (ie, 'reset') but actually as it is described in your post still holds, as far as I can see

Answer (score 2):

i recommed you using (group), may this help you

[read more](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing#advanced-layouts)

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, you need to rename layout & the file use layout.

e.g

```
l2_named/
    __layout-foo.svelte
    level_2_named@foo.svelte
```

The layout file added `-foo`, and the file use layout added `@foo`.