# __layout.reset has been removed in favour of named layouts

Tags: layout, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component, arrangeoverride

I have a page set up in this format

[original reset image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzfSZ.png)›

I looked at forums and it said i should change the inner layout page to __layout@reset.svelte. However when i do that, I get another error.

[reset image using @reset instead of .reset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY8La.png)

Does anyone know how i can put in a reset __layout inside of a folder and get it to override the parent layout?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to handle reset layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71789793/how-to-handle-reset-layout)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because __layout@reset.svelte would be looking for a __layout-reset.svelte file in it's current directory, or any parent directory directory, to be a sub-layout for. You don't have a __layout-reset.svelte file.

As Thomas Hennes mentioned in the other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71789793/how-to-handle-reset-layout). If you wanted to have it act like the reset, you'd need to create a __layout-reset.svelte file in the current folder or (more useful for the entire app, in the root folder) and have it be a blank `<slot />`. From there, you can do __layout@reset.svelte to which will allow you to make a completely new layout.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can solve this problem by fallowing this steps :

1. Create "__layout-choseNameYouWant.svelte" at the same level as "__layout.svelte"
2. Create "guides@theSameNameYouGaveForLayoutFile.svelte" at the same level as
   about.svelte

Answer (score 0):

*Layouts can themselves choose to inherit from named layouts*

1. create "__layout-root.svelte" at the same level as index.svelte and about.svelte with the following code
   `<slot/>`
2. create "__layout@root.svelte" in guides folder with the following
   `<slot></slot>`